# Equivalent of which for packages

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, the [`which`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) function is very useful for finding the absolute path of a function, class or method.

However, `which` doesn't work with packages (returns an empty result). Is there a way to find the absolute path of a package based on its name ?

---

**Edit**

Thanks toygan for pointing me in the direction of the `what` function. It indeed provides a lot of information on a Package, including the absolute path, but I can't make it work for packages in packages.

For instance, Imagine I have a folder `+MainPack` containing another folder `+SupPack` which contains a function `test`. `what` works on `MainPack`:

```
>> what('MainPack')

Packages in folder /home/.../+MainPack
```

but not on `SubPack`. Both

```
what('SubPack')
```

and

```
what('MainPack.SubPack')
```

return and empty structure.

So my question is now: what would be a general method to find the absolute path of a package, that works also for packages in packages ?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/165294-find-the-absolute-path-of-a-package 
Is this what you want?

Comment: First find mainpack, then concatenate with /+Subpack ?

Comment: @toygan: sure, but it doesn't really answer the question since you need a prior knowledge of where your package is located.

Comment: I know, I just tell it as a temporary solution. :)